# Android scale view as touch feedback

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

In my app I have a `Button`that I want to scale down a little while it is touched as a touch feedback instead of the background-color change.
If that makes it more clear, on websites in CSS I would do

```
:hover {transform(scale(0.9);}
```

I thought about adding an `onTouchListener` to my `Button`and then scale down the `Button` when that listener is activated. The problem is that I can't scale it back up afterwards since there is no `onTouchStopListener` or something like that. Also that would make my whole layout move a little since the button changed it's size. Is there a way to just change the size in which the view is drawn without changing the actual size of the view?